# View: Ignore a left join if it is not used?

Tags: oracle, optimization, join, oracle-12c, integration

I have a web service that references a **view** called `gis_sidewalks_vw`.

```
create table gis_sidewalks (
    id number(10,0),
    last_edited_date date
    );
insert into gis_sidewalks (id, last_edited_date) values (1, TO_DATE('2019/01/01 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into gis_sidewalks (id, last_edited_date) values (2, TO_DATE('2019/02/01 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into gis_sidewalks (id, last_edited_date) values (3, TO_DATE('2019/03/01 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into gis_sidewalks (id, last_edited_date) values (4, TO_DATE('2019/04/01 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
commit;

create table maximo_assets (
    id number(10,0),
    lastsyncdate date
    );
insert into maximo_assets (id, lastsyncdate) values (1, TO_DATE('2019/04/01 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into maximo_assets (id, lastsyncdate) values (2, TO_DATE('2019/03/01 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into maximo_assets (id, lastsyncdate) values (3, TO_DATE('2019/02/01 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into maximo_assets (id, lastsyncdate) values (4, TO_DATE('2019/01/01 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
commit;

create or replace view gis_sidewalks_vw as (
select
    s.id,
    s.last_edited_date as gis_last_edited_date,
    a.lastsyncdate as maximo_lastsyncdate,
    case 
        when s.last_edited_date > a.lastsyncdate then 1
    end sync_needed
from
    gis_sidewalks s
left join
    maximo_assets a
    on s.id = a.id
);

select * from gis_sidewalks_vw;

         ID GIS_LAST_EDITED_DATE MAXIMO_LASTSYNCDATE SYNC_NEEDED
 ---------- -------------------- ------------------- -----------
          1 01-JAN-19            01-APR-19                      
          2 01-FEB-19            01-MAR-19                      
          3 01-MAR-19            01-FEB-19                     1
          4 01-APR-19            01-JAN-19                     1
```

The view has a **left join** and a **calculated column**:

```
case 
    when s.last_edited_date > a.lastsyncdate then 1
end sync_needed

...

left join
    maximo_assets a
```

---

### **Scenario:**

The view & the web service are **multi-purpose**.

Purpose #1:

Serve up **only** the rows where `sync_needed = 1` to a cron task (synced weekly to a separate database).

Purpose #2:

Serve up **all the rows** in the view to a web map (map is in constant use).

---

### **Problem:**

In purpose #1, it makes sense to join to the `maximo_assets` table and generate the calculated column.

However, in purpose #2, it does **not** make sense to join to the `maximo_assets` table and generate the calculated column.

Unsurprisingly, with purpose #2, I am experiencing **performance issues** in the web map due to the unnecessary join.

---

### **Question:**

Is there a way to design the view so that it **ignores** the join to the `maximo_assets` table if the join is not being used?

For example:

```
select
    id,
    gis_last_edited_date
    --maximo_lastsyncdate
    --sync_needed
from
    gis_sidewalks_vw
```

[image]

Comment: I copied the wrong output and wanted to sort it out, so I temporarily deleted it.

Comment: How about defining two views. One with and one without the outer join ?

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind Yeah. Good idea. Although I think I'd have to A) Manually point the web service to the appropriate view during every sync, or B) create two web services, each pointing to separate views. I'm not totally against B, but my colleagues aren't very keen on managing two web services that are essentially duplicates (other than the views they point to).

Comment: Maybe you can have one view V1 (without the join) that has all the complex transformations, then another view V2 that joins V1 with the maximo table. The database will anyway flatten the nested views into a single query. You would still have two services for each table, but only one set of views with the complex transformation logic ...

Comment: Other than the hash join with full scans is as efficient as it gets when joining complete tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about it. Such a join without further information can not be skipped. Even if you do not select columns from maximo_assets, the join to it may increase the number of rows returned, because for 1 ID in gis_sidewalks, you can have multiple rows in maximo_assets with the same ID.

If the IDs are unique (or PK), and you make this known to the database by creating the proper constraints, then the above is not true anymore, and it will be able to skip the maximo_assets table:

```
alter table gis_sidewalks add primary key (id);
alter table maximo_assets add primary key (id);

select
    id,
    gis_last_edited_date--,
    --maximo_lastsyncdate,
    --sync_needed
from
    gis_sidewalks_vw;

        ID GIS_LAST_
---------- ---------
         1 01-JAN-19
         2 01-FEB-19
         3 01-MAR-19
         4 01-APR-19

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  f4p3b2huhfk5a, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select     id,     gis_last_edited_date--,     --maximo_lastsyncdate,
  --sync_needed from     gis_sidewalks_vw

Plan hash value: 1031306697

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |               |       |       |     3 (100)|          |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| GIS_SIDEWALKS |     4 |    88 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

The performance with the subquery you posted will not scale well.

Also, multi-purpose SQL is the root of a lot of performance problems, so handle with care.

Comment: Great answer! On a side note: I did some quick testing, and it looks like I only technically need a unique constraint on the joined table (`maximo_assets`), not the base table (`gis_sidewalks`) to achieve the desired effect. Of course, in reality, I would want a unique constraint on `gis_sidewalks`. I just thought I'd point this out for interest's sake.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like using a **subquery** instead of a join might do the trick:

```
create or replace view gis_sidewalks_vw_2 as (
select
    s.id,
    s.last_edited_date as gis_last_edited_date,
    case when
        s.last_edited_date > (select lastsyncdate from maximo_assets a where s.id = a.id) then 1
    end as sync_needed
from
    gis_sidewalks s
);


select
    id,
    gis_last_edited_date
from
    gis_sidewalks_2
```

[image]

---

Of course, a subquery would be much **slower** than a proper join.

But that would only effect purpose #1, not purpose #2.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the *real* table that this question applies to is the `asset` table in Maximo 7.6.1.1.

The `asset` table in Maximo does not have a unique index on the `assetnum` column (nor a primary key on `assetnum`).

However, it *does* have a unique index on the `assetnum` **and** the `siteid` columns.

- While the index isn't exactly what I want, perhaps it will help somewhat.
- If I add a WHERE clause to the underlying view (`where siteid = 'SERVICES'`) then the query in question only references the index; it does not do a full table scan.

---

```
create or replace view gis_sidewalks_vw as (
select
    s.id,
    s.last_edited_date as gis_last_edited_date,
    a.changedate as maximo_lastsyncdate,
    case 
        when s.last_edited_date > a.changedate then 1
    end sync_needed
from
    gis_sidewalks s
left join
    asset a
    on s.id = a.assetnum
where
    siteid = 'SERVICES'
);
```

---

```
select
    id,
    gis_last_edited_date--,
    --maximo_lastsyncdate,
    --sync_needed
from
    gis_sidewalks_vw
```

[image]

Comment: Related question here: [Does the ASSET table in Maximo have a primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58204992/does-the-asset-table-in-maximo-have-a-primary-key)